# Store text_field as datetime?? (datepicker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datetimepicker

My 'Events' table has 2 datetime values to store start and finish dates.

They used to be like this

```
.field
    = f.label t :event_start_date
    %br
    = f.datetime_select :start_date
  .field
    = f.label t :event_finish_date
    %br
    = f.datetime_select :finish_date
```

I used the datetime picker addon and it works fine visually. However, since the fields changed from datetime_select to text_field, the values are not stored when a new event is created.

This is how it looks right now:

```
.field
    = f.label t :event_start_date
    %br
    = f.text_field :start_date, :class=>"datetime_box", :size=>"17"
  .field
    = f.label t :event_finish_date
    %br
    = f.text_field :finish_date, :class=>"datetime_box", :size=>"17"
```

And this is the js in case anyone needs it:

```
$(function() {
    $('.datetime_box').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../images/pais_vasco_conciertos_teatro_musica_grupos.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

Any idea how to overcome this problem and store the values?

Events controller

```
def create

    categories = params[:category_ids] or []
    @event = Event.new(params[:event].merge(:user_id => current_user.id, :category_ids => categories))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save

        #Mailer to seek appoval
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This site works in 4 languages. This error only shows up under English language. So, I guess it has to do with the format..

Examples of format:
Spanish and French (works)

```
"start_date"=>"30/01/2013 16:39",
 "finish_date"=>"31/01/2013 16:39",
```

Basque(works)

```
"start_date"=>"2013/01/30 16:38",
 "finish_date"=>"2013/01/31 16:38",
```

English(does NOT work)

How can I make that MM/DD/YY work? Thanks again

```
"start_date"=>"01/30/2013 16:40",
 "finish_date"=>"01/31/2013 16:40",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the date, as a string, that is passed to the controller can be parsed by ruby.  One way to do this is to pass a date and time format to datetimepicker.  Experiment what format suits your needs and what can be parsed by ruby.

Try adding these options and see if that fixes your issue

```
$(elem).datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
```